# NHibernate- Prevent deletion on a particular entity (i.e. make read-only)

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, parent-child, readonly

How can I prevent NHibernate from deleting a single entity of a specific class?
A programmatic way I am using at the moment entails checking for the entity's unique field "Name".

Here's the scenario: I have a person and a group. The group can have persons and other groups. If the group named "Admins" is attempted to be deleted, it will not, due to transaction-level constraints that I enforce (specifically checking for the group's 'Name' column/field, as this is unique). So that's fine.

But now I'm thinking that if another group is created and the "Admins" becomes a sub-group of that, the check will fail. This will mean the deletion of "Admins". So I'm looking for a better way, other than traversing the parent/child containment tree, e.g. using NHibernate

I can't use a class-wide restriction such as 'class Mutable=false', I mean having a read-only restriction on one or two individual entities of a certain class.

Regards,

_NT

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own implementation of IPreDeleteEventListener and hook into nhibernate's event system to programmatically stop and entity being deleted.

[This](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/creating-an-audit-log-using-nhibernate-events.aspx) is an example of using listeners.

Comment: But that entails checking a lot of things manually. Is there no NHibernate-y way to do this?

Comment: Sorry I can't give a better suggestion for your case.

Let me put it this way. "Checking a lot of things manually" is all about domain complexity. ORM cannot help on this. No offence here but it may be the time to re-think about the domain object design, if it's not too late.

Comment: Why re-think the domain object design? I just need to make a couple of entities read-only in the best way possible -a better way than doing ifs and elses, IF that exists... Hence my question.

Comment: "become a child in a parent/child relationship" this lead me to domain object design issues. Sorry if I misunderstand your situation.

So are you talking about something like ORM-level Foreign Key checking? That does not exist in NH.

Comment: To be more precise: I have a person and a group. The group can have persons and other groups. If the group named "Admins" is attempted to be deleted, it will not, due to DAL-level (non-NHibernate atm) constraints that I enforce (specifically checking for the group Name column/field). So that's fine. But now I'm thinking that if another group is created and the "Admins" becomes a sub-group of that, the check will fail. This will mean the deletion of "Admins". So I'm looking for a better way, other than traversing the parent/child containment tree, e.g. using NHibernate

Comment: My personal practice is do this kind of checking on service layer, rather than in data access layer.

Back to your question. No. There should be no configuration/mapping to help you out in this case. And I don't think any other ORM can help it.